# Android Facebook SDK - programmatically login user

Tags: android, android-facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am using the following sample project (which im trying to modify):
https://github.com/fbsamples/android-3.0-howtos/tree/master/PublishFeedHowTo

There is a separate LoginButton and a Share Button in the project. The LoginButton is the widget from the Facebook SDK. I want to have a single button that will log in the user if its not already logged in and then automatically perform the share action. I couldn't manage to open a session programmatically. What code should I write to be able to login the user from my custom button or via code?

The code bellow is part of the sample project, all the session logic is encapusulated inside the LoginButton widget. I need to be able to perform the same action through my own button / code.

```
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
```

Although I found other threads on this topic, I couldn't find any answer. I don't want to use third party libraries, I would like to know if I can achieve this with the official Facebook SDK for Android.

Answer (score 1):

An easier although hackier solution is to add the login button to the layout and set the visibility to gone. You can then just call performClick() on the LoginButton and the login workflow will start.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
        findViewById(R.id.btn_login_with_facebook).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showProgressDialog();
            Session.OpenRequest openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(LoginActivity.this);
            openRequest.setCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {
                @Override
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                    if (state == SessionState.OPENED) {
                        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                                new FacebookLoginGraphUserCallback(restManager.getUserAdapter()));
                    } else if ((state != SessionState.OPENING) && (!session.isOpened())) {
                        hideProgressDialog();
                    }
                }
            });
            Session.openActiveSession(LoginActivity.this, true, openRequest);
        }
    });
```

This is code from one legacy project I'm not sure that it's fully functional with latest facebook-sdk but it should give you the main idea. But doing such things means that you will have to do all session related work by yourself.

If I understood you correctly it seems to me that better solution is to set  session status callback for native facebook login button. In this case you will be able to do whatever you want after user is logged in.